# Most performant way to increment dates

Tags: objective-c, nsdatecomponents

I'd like to increment over days in a loop, so that it counts `2012-11-10`, `2012-11-11`, `2012-11-12`, …

What's the most performant way to achieve this?

```
NSDate *iterationDate = [NSDate date];

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [comps setYear:0];
    [comps setMonth:0];
    [comps setWeek:0];
    [comps setDay:1];
    [comps setHour:0];
    [comps setMinute:0];
    [comps setSecond:0];
    iterationDate = [currentCalendar dateByAddingComponents:comps toDate:iterationDate options:0];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need all the intermediate `NSDate`s, just pull `comps` out of the loop:

```
NSDate *iterationDate = [NSDate date];
NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[comps setYear:0];
[comps setMonth:0];
[comps setWeek:0];
[comps setDay:1];
[comps setHour:0];
[comps setMinute:0];
[comps setSecond:0];

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    iterationDate = [currentCalendar dateByAddingComponents:comps toDate:iterationDate options:0];
}
```

---

You can achieve something similar using CoreFoundation APIs:

```
CFCalendarRef calendar = CFCalendarCreateWithIdentifier(0, kCFGregorianCalendar);
CFAbsoluteTime at = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
const CFOptionFlags options = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < NIter; ++i) {
    if (0 == CFCalendarAddComponents(calendar, &at, options, "d", 1)) {
        assert(0 && "uh-oh");
    }
    CFDateRef date = CFDateCreate(0, at);
    // store result
    CFRelease(date);
}
CFRelease(calendar);
```

That measured out to be 33% faster than Foundation. It's even faster if you don't need to create the CFDates and can simply store the `CFAbsoluteTime` values.

Comment: okay - and then it's the most performant way? so nothing faster than `dateByAddingComponents`?

Comment: @swalkner yeah - CF was the fastest i tried, assuming you need all the niceties the APIs you use are needed (e.g. calendar, locale, timezone, etc.).

Comment: I don't need the CFDate, but a NSTimeInterval; is it possible to get it from CFAbsoluteTime?

Comment: @swalkner yes. `CFAbsoluteTime`, like `NSTimeInterval`, represents seconds using a `double`. so you just need to decide where to subtract to get the result you want.

Answer (score 2):

I think that your way is not bad, just do not allocate each time the `NSDateComponents` object (`comps`):

```
NSDate *iterationDate = [NSDate date];
NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[comps setDay:1];
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) 
    iterationDate = [currentCalendar dateByAddingComponents:comps toDate:iterationDate options:0];
```

Another way could be (this should be faster, but needs to be tested ...):

```
NSDate *iterationDate = [NSDate date];
int daysToAdd = 1;  
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
       iterationDate = [iterationDate addTimeInterval:60*60*24*daysToAdd];
```

Comment: The second way won't work if it goes over a day where there is a transition between daylight savings